# $F,$ a finite field of characteristic p, is a vector space over the field $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

The question is to show that $F$, a finite field of characteristic p, is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. However, I'm not sure how to interpret the question.

More specifically, I know a vector space needs to be closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition, and it also needs to satisfy laws such as the commutative laws, associative laws, and distributive laws. But how do I show that? For example, if I'm showing the associative property, i.e. $$\alpha(\beta u) = (\alpha \beta) u,$$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and is $u$ an element of $F$? Similarly, if I want to show $$(\alpha  + \beta) u = \alpha u + \beta u$$ and $$\alpha(u + u') = \alpha u + \alpha u',$$ where do these $\alpha, \beta, u, u'$ belong to?

Also, do I utilize the associative, distributive, and commutative laws in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ here?

Comment: Just use the prime subfield as the scalars, multiply as usual.

Comment: "Also, do I utilize the associative, distributive, and commutative laws in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ here?" Actually you need these laws in $F$ for some of the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Any ring $R$ that contains a (commutative) field $K$ as subfield has a $K$-vector space structure, using the multiplication in $R$ by elements of the subfield $K$ to define scalar multiplication (and addition is addition in the ring). All required axioms are implied by the ring axioms. This applies in particular if $R$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$, with $K$ the $p$-element subfield.